# Downgrade macOS 10.14 to 10.13 using Migration Assistant

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, migration

I am currently running the macOS 10.14 beta on my Macbook and I wish to downgrade to High Sierra (10.13). I do have time machine backups from when I was still on 10.13, but I want to keep all my current files.

Is it a valid idea to instead just do a clean install of 10.13, then use migration assistant to transfer my files from backups when my computer was running 10.14? Can migration assistant even move files from a time machine backup running a later OS to a computer running an older OS?

I am only looking to migrate files and applications. I've done all the development work I needed in 10.14 and no longer need it. I have not added any server configurations or anything like that.

Comment: @danielAzuelos edited

Answer (score 2):

## Theoretical answer

This operation will fail.

Migration assistant is a huge procedure made to make all the conversions necessary to go from an **older** version of MacOS X to
the **running** one.

For example, the `Mojave` (10.14) version of `Migration Assistant` is configured to correctly convert the Users and System files from a `High Sierra` (10.13) set to a `Mojave` running environment.

The `High Sierra` (10.13) version of `Migration assistant` doesn't know the specific changes of `Mojave` (10.14) because they weren't known at its date of conception. Then this version cannot do a migration from `Mojave` to `High Sierra`.

On the other hand, the `Mojave` version of `Migration Assistant` does know the specific changes from `High Sierra` to `Mojave` but some of them might be not reversible, and this is usually not documented by Apple (this is bad: Apple is convinced none of its users is interested in this information).

## Practical answer

Your proposed migrition might succeed (my raw estimate: 25%).

**If** you didn't made system modification or specific development on Mojave,

and **if** Apple didn't put in place a basic verification of the origin version of MacOS X, (is the origin version **older** than the target one?),

**then** you could try to run `Migration Assistant` from `High Sierra` to migrate **only** Users files from your `Mojave` backup to your running `High Sierra` environment.

## Experience return

Please add your personnal success or failure as an answer, since this might help many other Mac users.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard such a method to downgrade. It is from a Chinese forum: https://www.v2ex.com/t/511804.

- (disable SIP)
- modify '/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist' to trick the installer to think it is a lower version
- Do an **overlay installation** of High Sierra
- Handle some conflicting Apps (e.g. reinstall iTunes)
- (enable SIP)

Try at your own risk.

---

Safely, you can always backup your current whole system and manully migrate personal files, Apps and settings (/Library/.., ~/Library/..). That's a tremendous work, though.

Comment: Sounds skeychy​